# How to know mediatype selected in photoLibrary before didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo in Swift?

Tags: swift, uiimagepickercontroller, gallery

I need to know the mediaType selected before didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo to be able to allow editing according to the type.

If you select video it will be true and if you select image it will be false.

In the case sourceType = .camera I have done it this way:

```
cameraController.allowsEditing = cameraController.cameraCaptureMode == .video
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by select `mediaTypes`

```
 var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
```

**For camera:**

```
if UIImagePickerController .isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera) {
   cameraController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera
   cameraController.allowsEditing = cameraController.cameraCaptureMode == .video

   self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil
 }
```

**For Video from gallery: you can select media type:**

```
cameraController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary
cameraController.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie as String]
cameraController.allowsEditing = true
self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

**For Only images:**

```
cameraController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary
cameraController.allowsEditing = false
self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

For More info, you can follow link: https://medium.com/@deepakrajmurugesan/swift-access-ios-camera-photo-library-video-and-file-from-user-device-6a7fd66beca2

Comment: The problem is that my mediaTypes are image and movie: picker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie as String, kUTTypeImage as String]

Comment: according to your requirements, You need to open only video and only images at a time. If you select both at a time then you cannot decide  allowsEditing before didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo